# How to deploy MobileFirst CLI application to an android device?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I am using MobileFirst CLI 7.1.  I want to deploy my MobileFirst CLI application to an android device. How can I do that?

In studio i use to get a projected generated when I right click > Build and depoly for all environments.

Also I want to know how can I target remote server. (In Studio we had an option to deploy to remote environment.)

Do we have any commands for achieving the above two?

Comment: You'll probably find this helpful: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/setting-up-your-development-environment/setting-up-the-android-development-environment/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In studio i use to get a projected generated when I right click > Build and depoly for all environments.

You need to have google's ADT tools installed and execute the commands from the command-line, or import the project into Google's Android Studio IDE.

> Also I want to know how can I target remote server. (In Studio we had an option to deploy to remote environment.)

In the Studio you did not have the option to "deploy to a remote server". You had the option to configure the application to point to a remote server (the properties you can edit in the worklight.plist/wlclient.properties file).

This feature does not exist in the CLI. After building the project, in case you want it to point to a different server, edit the properties in said file(s) to point to the remote server.